# Length of path of a reflecting wave

Tags: geometry

This is from a wave propagation book, but it's a geometry problem. From Achenbach's book "Wave Propagation in Elastic Solids (1975) on page 204 he calculates the distance a wave reflecting has traveled:

[image: schematic of problem]

If the wave traveling $ABDEF$ always reflects at an angle $\theta_0$, as shown at $A$, why is the path $BDE$ not equal to $\frac{3h}{\cos \theta}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok if I have understood your posting correctly, either this guy Achenbach got seriously confused or $\theta_0 = 30^{\circ}$. Unless there is something else going on, which I cannot see from the photo you have posted.

In general I agree with you that
$$\text{length} \, BDE =  \frac{3h}{\cos{\theta_0}}$$ 
Indeed, things get much simpler if we reflect the picture in the line $PD$ and get

[image]

where $E'$ is the image of $E$ with respect to the reflection in $PD$. Then the triangle $ADE$ is isosceles because $\angle \, DAE = \angle \, DEA = 90^{\circ} - \theta_0$ and the right angle triangle $BHE'$ has edge-length $HE' = 3h$ and angle $\angle \, BE'H = \theta_0$. Hence 
$$\text{length} \, BDE = BD + DE = BD + DE' = BE' = \frac{3 h}{\cos{\theta_0}}$$

However, if one assumes that 
$$\text{length} \, BDE = DE + BD = \frac{2 h }{\cos{\theta_0}} + \frac{2 h \cos{2\theta_0} }{\cos{\theta_0}}$$ having in mind that half of the triangle $DEE'$ is a right angled triangle, one notices that $$DE = \frac{2h}{\cos{\theta_0}}$$ and thus $$BD = \frac{2 h \cos{2\theta_0} }{\cos{\theta_0}}  = DE\cos{2\theta_0}$$ which is possible if and only if triangle $BDE$ is right angled with $AD = ED$, where $\angle \, EBD = 90^{\circ}$ and $\angle\, BDE = 2\theta_0$. However, as already observed earlier, in general triangle $ADE$ is isosceles. By definition, the line $EB$ is a median, because $B$ is a midpoint of $AD$, and in this particular case $EB$ is perpendicular to $AD$ (because $\angle \, EBD = 90^{\circ}$). Therefore $EB$ is a perpendicular bisector of segment $AD$ which is possible if and only if the isosceles triangle $ADE$ with $AD = ED$ is equilateral. Consequently, $\angle \, DAE = \angle \, DEA = 60^{\circ}$ and $\theta_0 = \pi - \angle \, DAE = 90^{\circ} - 60^{\circ} = 30^{\circ}$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. For the record, this is the only bit about geometry in the question, and interestingly there's no mention of $\theta = 30^{\circ}$. I was frustrated initially because, while I can check that those quantities are added are indeed equal, I was wondering why it was assumed right off the bat that you can add them that way. Glad to know there's a caveat!